# Greasemonkey script to monitor a website change

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, greasemonkey, monitoring, tampermonkey

I want to buy some product online, but every time more stock is added, it's all gone in 5 minutes or less :/

That's why I'm trying to make a small grease/tampermonkey script to watch that page and alert me when stock is available again...

Just to avoid reinventing the wheel I was wondering if there is any existing script for that purpose (I already googled, but couldnt find anything interesting in my search)

Also i'm not sure if greasemonkey allows scripts to be executed every X minutes (Actually I've never done this before with js/greasemonkey)... If not, any advice on a lead to follow or an alternative way to reach my means would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Which browser do you use?
I know two firefox extensions that could do the job
[Check4Change](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/check4change/?src=search) and [Update Scanner](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/update-scanner/?src=search) .

The code would be something like this, but you would have to know what elements you are looking for.

```
    if (document.getElementById('')) {
        alert("alert");
    } else {
        setInterval('location.reload();',15000); //page reload every 15s
    }
```